# Highlight outliers using zscore in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to style values that are outliers based on their z scores.
Example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
array=[[750.0, 1.1e-09, 'daljk', 6.0],
       [890.0, 1e-09, 'djfh', 8.0],
       [1720.0, 1e-09, 'dkhf', 4.0],
       [999.0, 1e-09, 'dkafh', 10.0],
       [890.0, 1e-09, 'dkajfh', 0.0005],
       [909.0, 1e-09, 'jkdafh', 6.0],
       [1002.0, 1e-09, 'dlfakh', np.nan],
       [990.0, 1e-09, 'ldkj', 3.0],
       [0.0001, 1e-09, 'dlkfj', 10.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ['A','B','C','D'])
df
```

gives

```
Out[4]:
           A             B       C        D
0   750.0000  1.100000e-09   daljk   6.0000
1   890.0000  1.000000e-09    djfh   8.0000
2  1720.0000  1.000000e-09    dkhf   4.0000
3   999.0000  1.000000e-09   dkafh  10.0000
4   890.0000  1.000000e-09  dkajfh   0.0005
5   909.0000  1.000000e-09  jkdafh   6.0000
6  1002.0000  1.000000e-09  dlfakh      NaN
7   990.0000  1.000000e-09    ldkj   3.0000
8     0.0001  1.000000e-09   dlkfj  10.0000
```

I have written the function below based on some code I got from another SO answer to highlight z scores GREATER THAN 1.5:

```
def highlight_outliers(x):
    color ='orange'
    #extract numeric columns
    c=x.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
    #create df of numeric cols
    df2=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=c)
    #calculate zscores
    df2=df2.apply(stats.zscore, nan_policy='omit').abs()
    #boolean mask of values greater than threshold value
    mask=(df2[c].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(np.Inf).replace(0, np.Inf).values<1.5)
    #create blank df of numeric cols
    df1=pd.DataFrame('',index=x.index, columns=c)
    #style locations which exceed threshold (fill orange) based on mask
    df1=(df1.where(mask, 'background-color:{}'.format(color)).reindex(columns=x.columns, fill_value=''))
    return df1
df_styled=df.style.apply(highlight_outliers, axis=None)
df_styled
```

Which gives:

[image: output image]

This is about right. However, my question is:
I don't want to highlight the NaN values and thought that the `.fillna(np.Inf)` part should fix it but it doesn't seem to.  How can I avoid highlighting the NaN values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a minor misconception here. Since `where` replaces all `False` values, you accordingly filtered by `<1.5`. However, `Inf < 1.5 = False`, hence it is highlighted later on. To "exclude" it, you rather need to insert `-Inf`.

From the documentation:

> Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other.

```
def highlight_outliers(x):
    color ='orange'
    #extract numeric columns
    c=x.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
    #create df of numeric cols
    df2=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=c)
    #calculate zscores
    df2=df2.apply(stats.zscore, nan_policy='omit').abs()
    #boolean mask of values greater than threshold value
    mask=(df2[c].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(-np.Inf).replace(0, -np.Inf).values<1.5)#
    #create blank df of numeric cols
    df1=pd.DataFrame('',index=x.index, columns=c)
    #style locations which exceed threshold (fill orange) based on mask
    df1=(df1.where(mask, 'background-color:{}'.format(color)).reindex(columns=x.columns, fill_value=''))
    return df1
df_styled=df.style.apply(highlight_outliers, axis=None)
df_styled
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great I didn't consider negative infinity. You also cleared up another question I had about why I have to use 'less than' instead of 'greater than' in the zscore logic, since 'where' replaces False. Thank you