# calculate zscores using groupby and highlighting using style

Tags: python, pandas

I want to highlight possible outliers in a dataframe based on zscore grouped by location.  I have used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70003657/highlight-outliers-using-zscore-in-pandas) to identify and score values but I can't seem to implement the .groupby correctly. For example `df.groupby('Loc').style.apply(highlight_outliers,color='red', threshold_val=1.5, axis=None)` gives 'AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'style'

Dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
array=[['Site 1',750.0, 1.1e-09, 'daljk', 6.0],
       ['Site 1',890.0, 1e-09, 'djfh', 8.0],
       ['Site 1',1720.0, 1e-09, 'dkhf', 4.0],
       ['Site 1',999.0, 1e-09, 'dkafh', 10.0],
       ['Site 1',890.0, 1e-09, 'dkajfh', 0.0005],
       ['Site 1',909.0, 1e-09, 'jkdafh', 6.0],
       ['Site 1',1002.0, 1e-09, 'dlfakh', np.nan],
       ['Site 1',990.0, 1e-09, 'ldkj', 3.0],
       ['Site 1',0.0001, 1e-09, 'dlkfj', 10.0],
       ['Site 2',7500.0, 1.1e-09, 'daljk', 6.0],
       ['Site 2',890.0, 1e-09, 'djfh', 8.0],
       ['Site 2',1720.0, 1e-09, 'dkhf', 4.0],
       ['Site 2',1, 1e-09, 'dkafh', 10.0],
       ['Site 2',890.0, 1e-09, 'dkajfh', 0.0005],
       ['Site 2',909.0, 1e-09, 'jkdafh', 6.0],
       ['Site 2',1002.0, 1e-09, 'dlfakh', np.nan],
       ['Site 2',990.0, 1e-09, 'ldkj', 3.0],
       ['Site 2',0.0001, 1e-09, 'dlkfj', 10.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ['Loc','A','B','C','D'])
df
```

Code not working:

```
from scipy import stats
css_colours={"red": 'red'}
def highlight_outliers(x,color,threshold_val):
    color=css_colours[color]
    #extract numeric columns
    c=x.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
    #create df of numeric cols
    df2=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=c)
    #calculate zscores
    df2=df2.apply(stats.zscore, nan_policy='omit').abs()
    #boolean mask of values greater than threshold value
    mask=(df2[c].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(-np.Inf).replace(0, -np.Inf).values<threshold_val)
    #create blank df of numeric cols
    df1=pd.DataFrame('',index=x.index, columns=c)
    #style locations which exceed threshold (fill orange) based on mask
    df1=(df1.where(mask, 'background-color:{}'.format(color)).reindex(columns=x.columns, fill_value=''))
    return df1

df.groupby(['Loc']).style.apply(highlight_outliers,color='red', threshold_val=1.5, axis=None)
```

I think I need to use 'transform' but I can't see how to apply it in this case. Creating a boolean mask is more intuitive to me (novice in python).
Expected output:

[image: output of values highlighted based on zscore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wrapper to keep your original function:

```
from scipy import stats

css_colours={"red": 'red'}

def highlight_outliers(x,color,threshold_val):
    color=css_colours[color]
    #extract numeric columns
    c=x.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
    #create df of numeric cols
    df2=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=c)
    #calculate zscores
    df2=df2.apply(stats.zscore, nan_policy='omit').abs()
    #boolean mask of values greater than threshold value
    mask=(df2[c].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(-np.Inf).replace(0, -np.Inf).values<threshold_val)
    #create blank df of numeric cols
    df1=pd.DataFrame('',index=x.index, columns=c)
    #style locations which exceed threshold (fill orange) based on mask
    df1=(df1.where(mask, 'background-color:{}'.format(color)).reindex(columns=x.columns, fill_value=''))
    return df1

def highlight_per_group(df, *args, **kwargs):
    return df.groupby(['Loc']).apply(highlight_outliers, *args, **kwargs)

df.style.apply(highlight_per_group, color='red', threshold_val=1.5, axis=None)
```

[image]